# Cordova FileTransfer show downloaded image

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, file-transfer

I´m downloading an image to the local storage with this code:

```
function saveImageToPhone(url, file) {

    var plat = device.platform;
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var url = url;
    if(plat == "iOS"){
      var filePath = cordova.file.dataDirectory + "files/img/" +file;
    }else{
      var filePath = cordova.file.applicationStorageDirectory + "files/img/" +file;
    }

    var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
    var uri = encodeURI(url);

    fileTransfer.download(
      uri,
      filePath,
      function(entry) {
        console.log(entry);
        deferred.resolve();

      },
      function(error) {
        console.log("error");
        deferred.resolve();

      },
      true
    );

    return deferred.promise;
  }
```

I´m displaying the image with:

```
<img src="file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/0C911347-00D1-4133-9186-D9653E64B572/Library/NoCloud/files/img/{{myimagename}}.jpg">
```

The above code works fine in android (with other src-path). The image gets downloaded, saved and showed up in frontedn.

With iOS at downloading the success function is called and xCode debugger shows me the positive response:

```
{"isFile":true,"isDirectory":false,"name":"3866938200000.1.jpg","fullPath":"/files/img/3866938200000.1.jpg","filesystem":"<FileSystem: library-nosync>","nativeURL":"file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/2A84F1F2-56D7-419A-B915-905C32FE851C/Library/NoCloud/files/img/3866938200000.1.jpg"}
```

But the image is not shown in frontend. Is there an option to inspect the file system of iOS (without jailbroken device) to check if the file is actually there? Or am I missing something? Is the src-path of my image correct?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have seen that this identifier "0C911347-00D1-4133-9186-D9653E64B572" is not the same after a new startup of the app. Is there a way to get that identifier persistent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am seeying that you are using cordova file plugin

You should save the path in the $scope, so you can append it to your html

In your controller:

```
$scope.path = cordova.file.dataDirectory
```

And in your html

```
<img src="{{path}}Library/NoCloud/files/img/{{myimagename}}.jpg">
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn´t know that the UUID is recalculated after an restart. Thanks!

Comment: Can you remove the upvote and let only the accepted answer please? I want to win a badge :)

Comment: Done. Thank you so much  ;)